# Duplicate tags [graylog] and [graylog2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We have these tags with the same description:

1. [graylog](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/graylog) with 14 questions
2. [graylog2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/graylog2) with 71 questions

The version history of Graylog is a bit confusing: It started as Graylog, then came Graylog2 (up to 0.92), then came Graylog (which is now at 2.51). So it makes no sense to have a tag *graylog2* as that would (if taken literally) only apply to very old versions of Graylog.

And since there will be Graylog 3.0 this summer, it makes even less sense (or do we really want to have a tag graylog3 etc?).

I question the need to have different tags for different versions.

Suggestion: Eradicate [graylog2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/graylog2) and retag all questions as [graylog](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/graylog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems legit.  I also note that a lot of the questions tagged with one are also tagged with the other, which is often a giveaway.  Let me get that fixed up...